# Using Regexpr with $

Tags: text-mining

Just a quick question, does anyone know how to use regexpr with "\$" ?  Essentially, I want to parse out strings and figure out what numeric value came after the \$ (for example "Get $50 off on purchases of new bed frames").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In regular expressions, `$` would denote the end of the string, and so if you want to match an actual $, you'd need to "escape" it, like `\$`.

In `grep` in R, you need to use `\\`, as follows:

```
x <- "Get $50 off on purchases of new bed frames"
grep("\\$\\d+", x)
```